# Lag on iOS when calling Microphone.Start() in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing a loop station kind of app which the user could tap on a slot to record his/her voice and tap again to replay their voice.

However, whenever I tap on the slot to record, there's a 0.5 sec lag... (It works fine on Unity Editor, but there's always a 0.5 sec lag on my iOS build)

below is my code:

```
public void OnPointerDown()
{  
    if (recordMode) {
        StartCoroutine(RecordCoroutine());
    } else {
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }
}

IEnumerator RecordCoroutine()
{
    //change the color to show that it's currently recording
    GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;

    //start recording
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = Microphone.Start(null, false, 1, 44100);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

    //stop the mic
    Microphone.End(null);

    //recover button color
    GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of the lag... I've been searching for a solution for an entire week but in vain...

P.S. I've already changed the DSP Buffer Size to Best latency to minimize the lag to play the audio clip.

Comment: Fixed this by checking the **Prepare iOS for recording** checkbox.

Comment: this checkbox does improve latency, but it forces audio output to be on the iPhone ear/call speaker, not the speakerphone speakers.... So it doesn't actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set DSP Buffer Size on Defailt. It worked for me.

Audio settings:

[image: Audio settings]

Comment: I have exactly the same issue but on Android. Changing DSP buffer didn't help, the lag stayed absolutely the same.